# Back4App CloudCode Invalid function using Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-cloud-code, back4app

Calling a cloud code function from javascript is throwing a "invalid function" error.

I have used parse.com a few years ago before the shutdown. i heard from back4app a few days ago and the basic setup was very fast. anyway i am not able to use the cloudcode function from javascript. my android app can successfully call functions within the same main.js. using the hello function to keep it simple. i have already tried to setup a webhook for this function. then i get the error "unauthorized". not sure if this needs a webhook.

main.js file

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

local html file

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/parse@2.1.0/dist/parse.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script>

  Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";
  Parse.initialize(
    'xxxx', // This is your Application ID
    'xxxx' // This is your Javascript key
  );

  Parse.Cloud.run('hello').then(function(r){
          console.log(r);
      }, function(error){
          console.log(error);
      });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try put Parse.masterKey = "<your Master Key>"; after Parse.initializer in yout html file. everything else seems okay

Comment: still the same error message "Invalid function: "hello""

Comment: I have the same environment here, I will try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it worked. The only change I made was to take the line breaks and comments from Parse.initialize and put my keys

Comment: thanks claudio.. i have created a fresh app and the code works as expected. i think that my "old" main.js file has some functions which are deprecated and caused this behavior..

Comment: ok I'm glad you have solved it